# How to use enum in chrome.* APIs

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make a chrome extention, in the document of [chrome.tabs](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-query) I can see:

> status ( optional enum of "loading", or "complete")

Where can I find an example of how to use/define this kind of enum?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass this as a string.

The enum part just means that only those values "loading" or "complete" are valid.

Comment: So you mean I cannot have something like *loading|complete*?

Comment: No you must pass one or the other in this case. If you want loading and complete tabs just dont pass `status`